Is it safe to modify system functions and distribute?
I am trying to add my definitions to FormulaData and looking through the source files It is clear that one can do that systematically by adding some DownValues to system functions and elements to lists, specifically:
Tools`MathematicaFormulas`FormulaData`Private`iFormulaData;
Tools`MathematicaFormulas`FormulaData`Private`MathematicaFormula;
Tools`MathematicaFormulas`FormulaData`Private`categoryAndSubcategory;

and some others. I know that this will work with my installation, but I want to distribute that and I don't know if internal system names typically change with updates(I guess not). My question: which problems should I consider before following this idea?
I want to add a lot of formulas, and looking at the source file, this really looks like the simplest option.

No. Please explain why you want to do this.  Sounds like an XY Problem

Well, maybe I wasn't clear. So I will try to simplify, I can solve my problem by typing AppendTo[Tools`MathematicaFormulas`FormulaData`Private`categoryAndSubcategory, {"myCategory", "mySubcategory"}]. Now, Is it a bad idea to write a .wl file that executes this and export it to other people's installation?

It would be better to create your own EntityStore in a .wl file and EntityRegister with that same file.  Altering built-in functions/structures is generally a ticking time bomb that may silently detonate.

See Set Up an Entity Store workflow.

"I can solve my problem by ..." It will be easier to give better solutions if you specify what the problem actually is.

The problem is to systematically add a lot of formulas to FormulaData I don't know how to reformulate that.

But why do you want to do that? Why not a custom EntityStore?

@Edmund Are you saying that with EntityStore and EntityRegister, you can make FormulaLookup and FormulaData  work with the OP's added formula data? -- Felipe, internals may not change often, but you cannot count on them staying the same.

@Domen I want to do that because it seems natural. I don't understand why would I create new entities if FormulaData already is the perfect framework to display my equations. --Michael E2, maybe I could clone the current files and add my definitions on them? This seems more stable across versions, since I would redefine FormulaData from scratch and this would be the case only when you load the cloned files.

@Felipe, fair enough, so you just want to add more entries to FormulaData. I don't think I've seen a failproof solution for this. There is for example a question Adding Entities to AirportData, but no proper answer ... As a general comment: You can modify system functions and this will very likely work if others use the same version of Mathematica, but you have no guarantee that the implementation will not change, and also you will not be notified about it, because they are internal functions.

@Domen Thanks, I will look in the reference. If I figure out a way to do this I will eventually post here.
